# React router dom navigate not working in useEffect for React 16, 17

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

So I discovered that calling **navigate('/a-path')** from the **useNavigate()** hook in react-router-dom doesn't work in my project. **navigate** doesn't throw any error, just doesn't navigate. Dispite calling it inside **useEffect** my Dev Tools logs a warning as if it was not in a **useEffect**. This I discovered using React 17 and showed it was the same for 16. In React 18 I still get the warning message, but it does the navigation!

So I start my app (React 16 and 17 now), go to /run in browser and nothing happens. I will refresh, nothing happens. I will make an edit in VSCode and save causing a hot reload and **then** it navigates! All the time "Manual run" works as expected.

There must be something about **run()** going off too early in some lifecycle.

Why doesn't the useEffect in Runner make the call to run wait until everything seems ready?

**RunnerPage.js**:

```
function Runner({ run }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    run()
  }, [])

  return <div onClick={run}>Manual run</div>
}

function RunnerPage() { 
  const navigate = useNavigate()

return (
    <Runner run={() => navigate('/goal')} />
  )
}
```

**App.js:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Copy App</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/run' element={<RunnerPage />} />
        <Route path='/goal' element={<GoalPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

[Chrome Dev Tools warning, React 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMX8Z.png)

I made a GitHub repo for you to try it. Folders 16 and 17 don't work. 18 does.
Run **npm install** then **npm start**, then go to /run and you'll see.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/PelicanQ/navigate-debug) https://github.com/PelicanQ/navigate-debug

I made the three versions by just changing the **react** and **react-dom** versions in package.json between ^16.0.0 ^17.0.0 and ^18.0.0 and re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Using Timeout solved my problem.

```
 setTimeout(function(){ navigate('/goal')}, 0);
```